# Ngx-bootstrap popover to appear at another location

Tags: angular, frontend, ngx-bootstrap

I' trying to make my popover appear at another [location](https://plnkr.co/edit/3MYfbIYtCCp49faal37H?p=preview).

Is it position popover at another location using ng-template?

```html
<ng-template #popmeover>
    <button type="button" (click)='pop.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <p>
    I am a popoverat another location trying my best to popover!
    </p>
</ng-template> 
            
         <br><br>
         <br><br>
         <span  [popover]="popmeover" #pop="bs-popover" container="body" >you click me popover should appear there!</span>
         <br>
         <br>
  
         <span >Make popover appear here!</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
<ng-template #popmeover>
    <button type="button" (click)='pop4.hide()' class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <p>
      I am a popoverat another location trying my best to popover!
    </p>
  </ng-template>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span (click)="pop4.show()">you click me popover should appear there!</span>
  <br>
  <br>

  <span [popover]="popmeover" #pop4="bs-popover" container="body">Make popover appear here!</span>
```

Working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gXrf7ZBnwvG7nfLmjOiD?p=preview)

Comment: @GoodJeans please accept it as answer . Glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS like this one:

```
  .popover {
  top: ###px !important;
  bottom: ###px !important;
  left: ###px !important;
  right: ###px !important; 
  }
```

Then apply it as a class for your popover

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue myself and the proposed solution was not an option.
The problem with ngx-bootstrap popover is that it uses both regular positioning and transform on the popover element to set the position so you can't override it.
I solved this issue by attaching the popover attribute to an empty span and change the position of the span before showing the popover so the popover follows the position of the span wherever it goes.

```
<span [popover]="myPopover"
    [outsideClick]="true" 
    (onHidden)="popoverIsOpen=false"
    triggers=""
    [adaptivePosition]="false"
    [isOpen]="popoverIsOpen"
    [style.top]="popoverPosition.y+'px'"
    [style.left]="popoverPosition.x+'px'"
    placement="right">
</span>
```